# SVN checkout using commit date for modified file time - TeamCity

Tags: svn, teamcity

We use TeamCity as our build server. It checks out/updates from an SVN repository and builds.
We have noticed that on occasion some projects with changes haven't been built.

I had it happen today so I logged onto box and noticed that the file date of the changed file was set to the commit date. As this was older than the output file (must have been built by another build configuration) MSBuild didn't think anything had changed so didn't build the project.

I looked at the settings in TortoiseSVN and 'Set file dates to the “last commit time”' was unchecked. I looked in %appdata%\subversion\config and use-commit-times is commented:

```
[miscellany]
#use-commit-times = yes
```

I can't find a setting on TeamCity. Anyone know if there is somewhere else this setting can be changed?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a clean checkout before you build anything in teamcity from svn. I have seen issues where timestamps are not updated or deleted files not removed from the folders when checking out from svn.

To do this on your vcs settings page, click on the checkbox that says "Clean files before build"